# Python: Ask to input again if "Enter" key is pressed without entering anything

Tags: python

Everything works fine but if I press "Enter" without entering anything. It shows error! Is there any way to ask user to input again till a valid input is given. More specifically, to ask user input again if just "Enter" is pressed.

```
def dice():
user = input("Do you want to roll the dice? ")
while user[0].lower() == 'y':
    num = randrange(1, 7)
    print("Number produced: ", num)
    user = input("Do you want to roll the dice? ")
```

When "Enter" is pressed, following error shows

```
Do you want to roll the dice? 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/a/Documents/Code/Learning_Python/dice_rolling_simulator.py", line 12, in <module>
dice()
File "C:/Users/a/Documents/Code/Learning_Python/dice_rolling_simulator.py", line 6, in dice
while user[0].lower() == 'y':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `user` in the condition of the `while`. This takes advantage of the facts that empty strings are evaluated to `False` and that the boolean operators in Python are short-circuited (if `user` is `False` then `user[0].lower() == 'y'` won't be evaluated, hence no `IndexError` will be raised):

```
while user and user[0].lower() == 'y':
```

Answer (score 1):

While loop to ask again and again.

```
Xin = input("blah blah blah")
while Xin == "":
    Xin = input ('blah blah blah')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes..! it is possible.**

```
def dice():
    i = 1;
    while i:
         user = input("Do you want to roll the dice? ")
         if user != None:
             i = 0

    while user[0].lower() == 'y':
        num = randrange(1, 7)
        print("Number produced: ", num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rephrase it.
Here's the whole code with comments and imports.

```
#importing random for randrange

import random

#defining rolling mechanism

def dice():

    #looping so that you can keep doing this
    while True:
    #asking for input
        user = input("Do you want to roll the dice? ")
        #if the user says  'y':
        if user.lower() == 'y':
            #it picks a random number from 1 to 6 and prints.
            num = random.randrange(1, 7)
            print("Number produced: ", num)
        #if not it will print that it doesn't understand the input and loop
        else:
            print("We don't understand your answer.")
dice()
```